# send an image back to the background color in css

Tags: html, css, image, background

I have a navigation bar which has a background color.

[image]

now I load an image to each elements of bar.

Now I want to send 50% of images behind to the bar and 50% shows above the bar.

how this is possible?

[image: here is picture of my page:]

But I want something like this:

Comment: I looked at your home page and it seems to be fine... using Chrome on windows 7

Comment: Thank you for commenting. The first picture is what I want, and the second one is my page. I want send 3 icons behind the blue background color. please help me

Comment: I see. I think CSS transitions would be the way to go on this one, maybe using position...

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/tpjk1cLu/2/
Using relative positioning and z-index, this can be accomplished.
HTML:

```
<div class="bar">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/385155/file-2329706823-png/Scanalytics-Smart-Home.png?t=1445265215183&width=65" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://www.convertcart.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/email-list-builder.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bar {
    z-index:105;
    background:#be4;
    margin-top:150px;
}
.bar a {
    position:relative;
    top:-60px;
}
.bar a img {
    z-index:-1;
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.bar a img:hover {
    top:-20px;
}
```

Hope this helps!